# CSV remove duplicates in 2nd column without deleting first row

Tags: sorting, awk, duplicates

I have a csv with 17 columns and many 1000s of rows.  In column 2, I am attempting to delete duplicates, but keep the first.

File example:

```
1001,Henry
1002,Dave
1003,Dave
1004,Tom
```

when I run:

```
sort -t, -k2,2 -u file.csv -o newfile.csv
```

the newfile.csv contains (wrong)

```
1001,Henry
1004,Tom
```

desired output:

```
1001,Henry
1002,Dave
1004,Tom
```

I've tried several things with awk as well, no luck.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text for format as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Otherwise, good first Q including input, required output, current output and .... gasp, some `code` ;-). Keep posting.

Comment: It's impossible for the script you posted to produce the output you say it does. Post a real (but still minimal) example that you and we can reproduce your problem with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk -F ',' '!seen[$2]++' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

This command is telling awk which lines to print. The variable $2 holds the entire contents of column 2 and square brackets are array access. So, for each second column of line in filename, the node of the array named seen is incremented and the line printed if the content of that node(column2) was not (!) previously set.

Comment: @Paras that's no more likely to work than the `sort` solution the OP posted, it'll just be slower.

Comment: @EdMorton noted. I'll read about awk and sort's internal working. Thanks for updating.